# C# - Set Height of ComboBox

Tags: c#, combobox, height

I want to set the height of a `ComboBox` (from the Windows Forms [Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx)s) to **X** *during runtime*.

I have

- the `DrawMode` Property set to `OwnerDrawVariable`, to specify that the
  items are drawn manually;
- the `IntegralHeight` Property set to false, to avoid the `Control` from automatically resizing itself;
- the `ItemHeight` Property of the `ComboBox` also set to **X**.

I've also overriden the `DrawItem` and `MeasureItem` events for the comboBox's items (see code below)

However, **setting the `Height` of the ComboBox at runtime only works if the `DropDownStyle` is set to `Simple`.**

I do this both ways, programmatically (modifying the `ComboBox`'s `Height` or `Size`) property, and using a `PropertyGrid` Control which I have on my App.

When I set the height of a `DropDown` or `DropDownList` `ComboBox`, I noticed that Windows automatically changes its height to another value: **Y** (which, after some debugging I noticed to be **X + 6** for some reason).

What am I missing? Why does this happen?

Here is the code from the handlers:

```
private void DrawItemHandler(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
  //Create a new font to write the item
  Font ComboItemFont = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 8, FontStyle.Regular);

  e.DrawBackground();
  e.DrawFocusRectangle();

  //Write the item's value
  e.Graphics.DrawString(((ComboBox) sender).Items[e.Index].ToString(),
                        ComboItemFont,
                        new SolidBrush(Color.Black),
                        e.Bounds);

  //Update the source's font to match the current font
  ((Control) sender).Font = ComboItemFont;
}

private void MeasureItemHandler(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
{
     //Do nothing
}
```

Comment: This is just how the winforms combobox is.  Consider 3rd party combo boxes otherwise.  The `DrawItem` and `MeasureItem` are for the list part of the control, not the edit part.

Comment: Not sure I know what you mean.  You are setting the control's font during the DrawItemHandler method — that will certainly change the height of the combobox since the height is determined by the control's font.  I would comment out that line.

Comment: I just did. The same problem happens. 

So I'm guessing the ComboBox's Font isn't related to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
 namespace WinForms 
 {
      public partial class Form1 : Form
      {
          public Form1()
          {
              InitializeComponent();
              comboBox1.Size = new Size(10,10);
          }
      }
 }
```

You can also change the `Size(Width,Height)` from properties view in Visual Studio

Comment: The problem is that I want to do this at runtime. When I change comboBox1's Height to X, Windows automatically changes it to Y instead.

I tried creating a PropertyGrid inside the App (and binding it to the ComboBox object) to change its Height manually, but I get the same mistake - I write "X" in the Height and "Y" shows in the Grid.

Comment: Your question : I want to set the height of a ComboBox (from the Windows Forms Controls) to X during runtime. So I understood that your using Property ComboBox.X and ComboBox.Y to change height and width at runtime and with my example above I am suggesting you to use Property ComboBox.Size that takes Width & Height and can set them at runtime

Comment: I do. I set ComboBox1.Size = (X, X) and Windows still changes it to (X, Y) at runtime. But only for DropDown and DropDownList comboboxes.